# Django Celery - how to perform a function AFTER retries have exhausted

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I added some code to my task's `on_failure` which deletes an object. My intention was to delete the object after the max retries occurred, but `on_failure` is called once per failure of the `run` method, rather than after failure of all retries. Is there another place to put this sort of functionality (e.g., `def after_exhaustion(...)`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The task [context](http://celery.github.com/celery/userguide/tasks.html#context) has a **retries** field which is the number of times the task has been retried. You can use it to determine when to delete your object.